# Getting error while uploading Table definiton to phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, syntax-error, mariadb

This is the .sql file I'm trying to upload on my Database in phpmyadmin.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.10.14
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost:3306
-- Generation Time: Dec 03, 2016 at 01:46 AM
-- Server version: 10.0.28-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 5.6.20

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `cryptic`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `cryptic_gameplay`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cryptic_gameplay` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `level` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `clear_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `attempts` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `cryptic_login_log`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cryptic_login_log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1s;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `cryptic_questions`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cryptic_questions` (
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hint1` text NOT NULL,
  `hint2` text NOT NULL,
  `answer` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`level`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `cryptic_users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cryptic_users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1000;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `cryptic_user_stats`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cryptic_user_stats` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `level` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

But, I'm getting an error i.e.

SQL query:

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `cryptic_login_log`

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cryptic_login_log` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
    `ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    `status` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1', 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1s
```

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1s' at line 14

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong. 
This code is actually from a github project, which is about creatig a cryptic hunt on PHP. I'm new to PHP and trying to learn in, I got this error while trying to follow the instructions.

Here is the link to that project [Enigma/Cryptic Hunt](https://github.com/ahnv/enigma)

Comment: Did you even try searching for "1s" in the script?

Comment: i got confused because of line 14 thing, it was on line 51, sorry I'm  really new to programming, it's my first time.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the "s" in `AUTO_INCREMENT=1s;` in `cryptic_login_log` table definition.

Comment: Thank you, got it